# vba to copy specific cells when values from two columns match

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to vba and need to find a way to copy certain cells between worksheets based on matching values. In sheet1, column A is a list of abbreviated names. I need to search sheet 2, column D for any matches. If a match is found, copy the cells in A, B, and C of sheet 2 and paste them into the corresponding location in sheet 1.

Comment: 1) record Macro, 2) vlookup function.  Google these two and you might have it done in no time

Comment: I don't think I can just record a macro as there are hundreds of separate matching values, not just a single value that I am looking for. I'm not overly familiar with the vlookup function. I've been trying to learn vba and often find code that I can modify to accomplish what I need but this is still eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also believe that the easiest way is using vlookup.
Might faster too...
You can use something like this if you like.
Haven't check it though.

```
Sub CopyBasedonSheet1()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Sheet1LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet2LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 1 To Sheet1LastRow
        For i = 1 To Sheet2LastRow
            If  Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value  = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 4).Value Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 2).Value  = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 3).Value  = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 4).Value  = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value
            Else
            End If
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly and is much simpler than what I was trying.